# Tkinter: Passing parameters to a python script executed by button

Tags: python, button, lambda, tkinter

I have a python script that I execute from the command line, and I pass to it some parameters from there as well. 
Now I'm designing the GUI to execute that script, so I want to execute the script after clicking a button, and passing the arguments from a `Listbox`. 
 
I have seen some suggestions that used `lambda` functions. However, I couldn't find any example of executing a whole different script that takes arguments from command line basically. 
I also tried `ecevfile`, but it executes the script without taking any parameters. 
How can I execute the script by a button press and passing the arguments as well?

Comment: You might be interested in [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run your script.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but you could write a function to make a batch file and use `os.startfile("batch.bat")`